# Find the arc length of lemniscate $r=2(\cos(2\theta))^{1/2}$

Tags: polar-coordinates, arc-length

I have to find the arc length of a lemniscate with polar equation $r=2(\cos(2\theta))^{1/2}$.

So far I got like
$\sqrt{4\cos(2\theta)+\left(-2\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}\right)}$.

I don't know how to proceed, I can't seem to figure out how to approach this.

Comment: what is the formula for the [arclength of a curve in polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Other_coordinate_systems)?

Comment: @robjohn its integral of sqrt(r^2 + (dr/dtheta)^2)

Comment: What do you get when you apply that?

Comment: @robjohn idk i get a weird eqn and im not sure how to proceed

Comment: i get like sqrt(4 cos 2theta + (-2 sin 2theta/sqrt(cos 2theta))

Comment: If you add what you have so far to your question, you might get more help.

Comment: @robjohn do u have the Answer to my qurstion?

Comment: I have put what you wrote in latex. Is that what you meant?

Comment: To the close voter: Why vote to close right after the OP added some context?

Comment: You squared $r$, but forgot to square $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)$. Otherwise, you are on the right track. However, as you can see from my answer, the integral is not simple. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @robjohn its a part of my maple project. ive done my maple part but we have to calculate it manually too. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}2(\cos(2\theta))^{1/2}
=-2(\cos(2\theta))^{-1/2}\sin(2\theta)
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
r^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2
&=4\cos(2\theta)+\frac{4\sin^2(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)}\\
&=\frac4{\cos(2\theta)}
\end{align}
$$
Doubling the length of one leaf, we get
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}
&=4\sqrt2\operatorname{K}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{\operatorname{AGM}\left(1,\sqrt2\right)}\\[6pt]
&=10.488230217168479242
\end{align}
$$
where $\operatorname{K}$ is the [Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) and, as Jack D'Aurizio comments, $\operatorname{AGM}$ is the [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).

[image: Lemniscate]

---

**A Derivation of the Integral**

I've stated several equivalent forms of the integral above. Here is the derivation of one of them.
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}
&=4\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm{d}2\theta}{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}\tag{1}\\
&=4\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{u\vphantom{u^2}}\sqrt{1-u^2}}\tag{2}\\
&=2\int_0^1v^{-3/4}(1-v)^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}v\tag{3}\\
&=2\,\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}\tag{4}\\
&=2\frac{\sqrt\pi\,\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}\tag{5}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: exploit the symmetry of $\cos(x)$
$(2)$: substitute $u=\cos(2\theta)$
$(3)$: substitute $v=u^2$
$(4)$: use the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$(5)$: $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$
$(6)$: $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)=\pi\csc\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\pi\sqrt2$ using [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)

Comment: I was debating adding that since the AGM converges very fast, but thought I might be getting too far out of the scope of the question already with elliptic integrals, but what the heck...

Comment: It also has an explicit value in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The EllipticK from Mathematica is not the same as in Wikipedia. I have adjusted things.

Comment: I always get tricked by that. Wonderful answer anyway.