# Find the length of the curve of $r^2 = a^2cos(2x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

I am trying to find the arc length for the lemniscate $r^2 = a^2cos(2x)$ using the equation $$\int \sqrt{r^2 + (\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2} \, d\theta$$

However, I end up with the integration of $\sqrt{sec(x)}$ which is too difficult to integrate. Is there any different path that I can following using the same formula to find the length of the curve? Is there a way to make this easier?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: and where are the bounds of the integral?

Comment: its comes out to be from 0 to pi/2

Comment: It should be $(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2$, not $\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}$.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474317/find-the-arc-length-of-lemniscate-r-2-cos2-theta1-2

Comment: @Teddy38 sorry by mistake. I used the correct formula while solving though

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html Apparently there is a specific integral used in the case of lemniscates - the elliptical integral - and there is no simpler form

Comment: k thanks @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Similarly how would you find the length of $r^3 = sin(3\theta)$. I end up with the integration of $sin (3\theta)^(-2/3)$

Comment: and $k$ assumed to be an integer?

Comment: $sin (3\theta)$ to the power (-2/3)

Answer (score 0):

If $r^2 = a^2 \cos 2x$ then
\begin{align}
2\frac{d r}{d \theta}r &= -2a^2 \sin 2x \\
\implies  \left(\frac{d r}{d \theta}\right)^2 r^2&=a^4 \sin^2 2x \\
\implies \left(\frac{d r}{d \theta}\right)^2 &= a^2 \frac{\sin^2 2x}{\cos 2x} \\
\implies r^2 + \left(\frac{d r}{d \theta}\right)^2 &= \ldots
\end{align}
once you get to this stage, noting that $$\cos 2\theta = \frac{r^2}{2a^2}$$ one can write
$$(\frac{d\theta}{dr})^2 = \frac{r^2}{4a^4 - r^4}$$

from which you should find
\begin{align}s &= \int_{0}^{r'}\sqrt{\frac{4a^4}{4a^4 - r^4}}dr \\
&= \int_{0}^{r'}\frac{2a^2}{\sqrt{4a^4 - r^4}}dr
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?